# ArcGIS Portal homepage altered without HTML change

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis-portal

After changing the region in REST services the carousel of images has stopped rotating, the white banner at the top has disappeared and icons at the bottom have shifted.  It seems like a page size setting for the homepage code has changed when the region changed.

I pasted the original backed up HTML back into the org setting and it did not have any effect.

Is this a JavaScript problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the relevant code/settings?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML does break when you change regions in the 'ArcGIS Portal Directory'.
To fix this you hopefully have your original HTML with proper formatting.. paste the SAME HTML from the text editor back into the 'My Organisation' general and home page configuration settings.
The settings then need to be saved after both of the HTML areas are updated and then the browser cache need to be cleared.
The homepage should revert back to normal.

Editing the HTML inside the portal can cause the HTML formatting to be compacted.